# Venia pwa + magento 2 categories and products issue

Tags: magento, progressive-web-apps, magento2, venia

1. Sucessfuly connected magento 2 to venia pwa
2. All category levels are visible in venia pwa all is ok

Issue: I can open only first and last category, any of other cannot be opened, got oops error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHskk.png)

What can i do?
Urls is ok at both sides, magento backend url is ok at venia side, i don't know what to do . .